# highest value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

What I would like to do is loop through my_family and return the member with the highest Age.

```
my_family = {
    "member1": {"Name":"Person1","Gender": "Male","Age": 24},
    "member2": {"Name":"Person2","Gender": "Male","Age": 32},
    "member3": {"Name":"Person3","Gender": "Female","Age": 62}
}
```

My attempt is below:

```
k = my_family.keys()  
v = my_family.values()

def highAge():
    for k,v in my_family.items():
        if "Age" in my_family.items():
            print("Age found")
    else:
         print("Failed")

highAge()
```

The current output is Failed.

Comment: Where do you compare the ages in the given code?

Comment: hint, it is because `Age` is inside a dictionary within your dictionary, that is why the member check (`in`) fails

Comment: `print(max([v["Age"] for k,v in my_family.items()]))`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about keys then here is a simple solution to your problem.

```py
my_family = {
    "member1": {"Name":"Person1","Gender": "Male","Age": 24},
    "member2": {"Name":"Person2","Gender": "Male","Age": 32},
    "member3": {"Name":"Person3","Gender": "Female","Age": 62}
}

person_with_max_age = max(my_family.values(), key=lambda f: f["Age"])

print(person_with_max_age)
```

```sh
>> {'Name': 'Person3', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': 62}
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix:

Your first 2 lines are superfluous, delete them:

```
k = my_family.keys()  
v = my_family.values()
```

Then in the `if` statement change `my_family.items()` to `v`, and append the `break` command. So your full program will be

```
def highAge():
    for k, v in my_family.items():
        if "Age" in v:
            print("Age found")
            break
    else:
         print("Failed")

highAge()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort your dictionary by the age and take the last item

```py
my_family = {
    "member1": {"Name":"Person1","Gender": "Male","Age": 24},
    "member3": {"Name":"Person3","Gender": "Female","Age": 62},
    "member2": {"Name":"Person2","Gender": "Male","Age": 32},
}

my_family_sorted_by_age = sorted(my_family.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]["Age"])
print(my_family_sorted_by_age[-1])
```